# What is the procedure of disk or data node failure and recovery in hadoop

Tags: hadoop, procedure, data-recovery

As I know the procedure for block and replica storing in Hadoop is conducted by the BlockPlacementPolicy function or process, but this is for the initial storing procedure (first time when the data is stored on the HDFS system). I am interested which process or java function is responsible for recovering (by recovering I mean solving the problem of underreplication) the data after disk or Datanode failure. My idea is to change the function-in-charge, to work according my needs, this means to maintain the number of replicas and store the new replicas (recovered replicas) on disk of my interest.

Answer (score 0):

When a node fails, the blocks stored on there no longer count as being available for HDFS. You can easily see this by looking at the number of under replicated blocks when a node fails or is disabled.

In general, the system will try to solve underreplication when it occurs (and when capacity is available). So basically the solution that you want to build should already be in place.

Note: Hadoop does not try to recover data from broken nodes, but simply replicates the relevant blocks based on non-broken nodes.

Comment: sorry, I used the word recovery, i was thinking of solving the underreplication. I know that this procedure is automated by Hadoop. My question is about the procedure and which process is in charge of solving the underreplication situation.

Comment: I know that, when Namenode doesn't receive heartbeat from a Datanode, it starts with solving the underreplication, but i want to know the details about which process guides the procedure, who is the conducter of the procedure of solving the underreplication, what java functions are in charge.

Comment: @JovanKaramac Perhaps that would be the [Balancer](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/HADOOP-1652).